# ow to hold keyup method until type 3 letters in angular

Tags: angular

How can I stop a function running until a specific number of characters are pressed in angular using keyup method?

this is my html file...

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Search Occupation By" name="occuSearch" (selectionChange)="occupationSearchChangeAction(occuSearch)" 
[(ngModel)]='occuSearch' >
  <mat-option *ngFor="let occup of occupList" [value]="occup.occupSearch" >{{ occup.occupSearch }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

this is my ts file

```
aaaaa = 'Name';
occupationSearchChangeAction(occup) {
    this.aaaaa = occup;
    console.log(this.aaaaa);
}
```

so how i make this using type script?

Comment: Please show more of your code, it's unclear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check the size of the incoming string in your `occupationSearchChangeAction` function:

```
occupationSearchChangeAction(occup) {
    // only process if occup is at least 3 characters long
    if (occup.length >= 3) {
        this.aaaaa = occup;
        console.log(this.aaaaa);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input keyup="occupationSearchChangeAction(occup)">
    </input>
```

**.JS**

```
function occupationSearchChangeAction(occup){
    if(occup.length == 3){
      //run code
      }
   }
```